# Find total resistance of this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance

[image: circuit]

I want to find the total resistance between A and B.
This is a HOTS mcq, which has the following options:

- A: 45\$\Omega\$
- B: 15\$\Omega\$
- C: 5\$\Omega\$
- D: 22.5\$\Omega\$

A book says that the answer is 5\$\Omega\$ as R1, R2 and R3 are parallel. But I cannot understand how can they be parallel? Our science teacher said that R1, R2 and R3 are in a series, so he said that total resistance R=45\$\Omega\$.
The book that says that the answer is 5\$\Omega\$, does not have the method to find it out.

I tried that:

1. All are in series :- 45\$\Omega\$
2. 15\$\Omega\$ is parallel with 15+15+15\$\Omega\$ and with one more 15\$\Omega\$, which would turn into : 45/7\$\Omega\$, which is not possible.
3. R3 is parallel with R1 and R2, as well as in a series with R2.
   R1 is parallel with R2 and R3, as well as in a series with R2 and R3. But then I cannot determine the method to get the answer.

So I am confused between 5\$\Omega\$ and 45\$\Omega\$. I think as the book says, the answer must be 5\$\Omega\$, but what is the method?

Comment: The first step in these types of problems is always to redraw the circuit in a way that isn't nonsensical.

Comment: The book is correct.  My professor explained it pretty well like this.  Two things are in *parallel* when they both connect to the same nodes. Sounds simple, but that's all it is! Look at the left resistor, it connects node A with node B through the bottom short. The middle resistor connects node A and B through both shorts, and the right resistor connects A and B with the top short.

Comment: Another way to think of it is current essentially always takes the path(s) of least resistance proportionally, right? So if you follow each path, you'll see there are 3 ways of traveling from A to B, each going through just 1 resistor. Current will NEVER travel through more than 1, since there is always an easier path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the book is pretty correct as the circuit is like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnJpe7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
This circuit would be in series if there were no wires shorting the circuit and then net resistance would be 15 ohm.

Comment: While your explanation may be correct, your diagram doesn't match the original. His has 3 x 15R while yours has 3 x 5R.

Comment: yeah you are right i just forgot resistances were of 15ohm however that will have no effect on concept that i have used in the circuit. thanks for correction brhans

Answer (score 7):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhr1XP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Try redrawing the circuit with the 'A' connections in a bar at the top and the 'B' connections in a bar at the bottom (or use left/right).

They've deliberately made it confusing.

If you're redrawing, here's a set of guidelines that Olin wrote up:

[Rules and guidelines for drawing good schematics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, R1, R2 & R3 are parallel to each other & hence, resultant resistance is 5 ohms. While finding equivalent resistance between any two points, imagine that you're travelling from one point to the other. Let's consider here that we're travelling from A to B.

One end of R2 is short-circuited to A & other end is short-circuited to B. Same is the case for R1 & R3.

That's why they fall parallel to each other & total resistance is 5 ohms.

Comment: Your answer seems correct as the calculator on http://falstad.com/circuit/ says the same.